# How to merge or delete an element in a list that duplicates the previous item?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
output = ['9', '-', '-', '7', '-', '4', '4', '-', '3', '-', '0', '2']
```

and I'm trying trying to reduce the '-','-' section to just a single '-', however, haven't had much luck in trying.

```
final = [output[i] for i in range(len(output)) if output[i] != output[i-1]]
final = 9-7-4-3-02
```

I've tried that above, but it also reduces the '4','4' to only '4'. So any help would be great.

Comment: so only reducing `-` ?

Comment: Why not add `if output[i] != output[i-1] and ouput[i] == '-'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the item is equal to the previous item **and** to `'-'`, which can easily be done in Python using `a == b == c`.

Note that you should also handle the first character differently, since `output[0] == output[0-1]` will compare the first item with the last item, which might lead to invalid results.

The following code will handle this:

```py
final = [output[0]] + [output[i] for i in range(1, len(output)) if not (output[i] == output[i-1] == '-')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The zip() function is your friend for situations where you need to compare/process elements and their predecessor:

```
final = [a for a,b in zip(output,['']+output) if (a,b) != ('-','-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
output = ['9', '-', '-', '7', '-', '4', '4', '-', '3', '-', '0', '2']
r = [j for a, b in gb(output) for j in ([a] if a == '-' else b)]
```

Output:

```
['9', '-', '7', '-', '4', '4', '-', '3', '-', '0', '2']
```